# Is it reasonable that /var/log/kern.log not found on node?

Tags: linux-kernel

Linux version:
3.14.25-00387-g38b1460 #2 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 1 14:26:11 CEST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Sometimes, the kern.log is not found, don't know why.
I know there is rotating configs, but if the file is not there when we want to collect kern.log, is this an issue, anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.syslog-ng.com/syslog-ng-faq/

“If there are multiple processes reading ''/proc/kmsg'', a race condition occurs and the process which loses the race essentially deadlocks until the next kernel message is generated, when a new race condition occurs.”

Above is somehow one possible answer, and we see on node that two processes may have chance to access that kmsg file.